# Things you stick your face through for photos

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, photography

What is the name of those things where you put your face in a hole and someone takes a picture so it looks like you're something else? E.g. a cardboard/wooden stand with a picture of a pirate and a mermaid with the faces cut out, and you and your friend put your faces through the hole so in the photo you look like a pirate and a mermaid?

Comment: Unimpressively, they are called [face-in-hole](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&biw=1093&bih=501&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=fnnrW9aNK66l_QaG5rHABw&q=face+hole+prop&oq=face+hole+prop&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30.146943.151455..153761...0.0..0.1142.7964.0j1j2j2j1j3j4j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j35i39j0i67j0i10j0i5i30.hZZZLs7Clmw) props.

Comment: Wow! We have a "photography" tag!

Comment: @Scott - Yeah, with 15 questions.

Comment: This Q is better asked on [photography.se]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a definitive name for it, but here are some of the names it's called. Personally I like "peep board" and it works just fine. Try searching on the internet and see the results.

- peep board
- peep-hole board
- seaside peep-through board
- your-face here cutout
- carboard cutout
- comic foreground
- seaside photo board
- happy fun time face board

Sources:

1. https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080715124528AAPPp9p
2. https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=611546
3. https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1156485

Answer (score 0):

They're called stand-in / cut out photo stands